# how can i use a function in ngIf condition Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i have 2 functions

```
loadItems(): void {
this.service.query().subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Item[]>) => 
 (this.items = res.body || []));
 }
 
loadAuditByItem(item: Item) {
this.service.auditByItem(item.id!).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<ItemAudit[]>) => 
(this.auditByItem = res.body || []));
 }
```

i want to display informations from both loadItems() and loadAuditByItem() at the same page
i managed to display the name and description from loadItems() but i need to display "createdBy" from loadAuditByItem(item)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngIf="loadAuditByItem(item)">
        <span>Name: {{ item.name}}</span>
        <span>Description : {{ item.description }}</span>
        <span>Created by: {{ auditByItem .createdBy}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: loadAuditByItem should return a boolean result to use it with ngIf

Comment: could it return a boolean result and information about the item at the same time ?

Comment: If you need multiple values on return maybe a good idea is to use a "hidden" attribute instead of ngIf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a function call in `ngIf` is very bad for performance *(you could add a `console.log` and check your console to see how many times it is been called)* instead you could use [Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), that had been said let me give you a solution for your use case:

```js
import { forkJoin, Observable, of, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
...

  public items$: Observable<Item[]>;

...

  loadItems(): void {
    // please consider to edit your backend API to return all data in one API call
    // since this nested calls will lead to N+1 calls problem.

    this.items$ = this.service.query().pipe(
      map((res: HttpResponse<[]>) => res.body || []),
      switchMap((items: []) => {

        if (items.length === 0) {
          return of([]);
        }

        return forkJoin(
          items.map((item: any) =>
            this.service.auditByItem(item.id).pipe(
              map(audit => {
                item.audit = audit;
                return item;
              })
            )
          )
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)">
    <div>
        <span>Name: {{ item.name}}</span>
        <span>Description : {{ item.description }}</span>
        <span>Created by: {{ item.audit.createdBy}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Bonus:*
It is not good to expose `HttpResponse` from the service, and it is better to return only the `Item[]` and encapsulate the `HttpResponse` there.

Answer (score 1):

I would have return the Observable so that *ngIf handle the subscription with the [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

```js
public loadAuditByItem(item: Item): Observable<any> {
    return this.service.auditByItem(item.id!);
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngIf="loadAuditByItem(item) | async as audit">
        <span>Name: {{ item.name }}</span>
        <span>Description : {{ item.description }}</span>
        <span>Created by: {{ audit.createdBy }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not a right solution, (I know it is gonna work BUT) be careful of the `loadAuditByItem` function calls, you could check the network tab in your devtools, so you do not end up with a DDOS attack to your own server.

Comment: @TarekBaz I upvote your answer as it is more complete.